# Yii2 ArrayHelper::map() format date

Tags: arrays, date, yii2, format, helper

I have following in index.php/gridview widget:

```
'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Hwzrpp::find()->all(), 'id', 'wa'),
```

`wa` is a date stored in DB in the format: `2018-12-12`. Is there a quick way to apply another format with e.g. `:date` or `Yii::$app->formatter->asDate()` somewhere in `map()` to it, so that I can show date like this: `12.12.2018` in the dropdown? I don't find anything regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `Closure` as third argument for `map()`:

```
'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Hwzrpp::find()->all(), 'id', function ($data) {
    return Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($data->wa);
}),
```